# encapsulation, data-hiding, setters/getters in c++

Tags: c++, encapsulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

while writing class in c++, usually methods are made public, and attributes are made private/public, so that these attributes cant be accessed from outside.

But when we use getters/setters, these attributes can be easily accessed,modified from outside. So, why to make them private/protected in first hand; if we are going to use setters/getters later on to modify.

I have been confused with this question. Nice explanation would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - should have known better - this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091; voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

You should never supply getters & setters by default, only if the use case of the class requires them. This will almost never be true for setters, and only occasionally for getters.

Consider the `std::string` class. Does it make sense to give access to its private data members? No, only one of them is exposed (the current length) via the `size()` getter, and none via setters.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add some logic into setters/getters in future.
2. Sometimes getters/setters can operate with abstract things... like count in dynamic arrays

Answer (score 0):

As Adelf stated, adding logic.
Also the option to only write or only read a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit access to attributes, i.e. if you will write getter without setter, attribute will be read-only. Also some useful logic can be added i.e. for setter - verification of border terms of value.
Also you can add getter for attribute the value of which is calculated at a call